# collidesWithItem() function not detecting collision (PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm writing an application that allows the user to add items to a scene. I dont want any new items being drawn over items that have already been drawn and to do that I decided to use the collidesWithItem() function to detect collision. With my code i still can draw over added items even though there is obviously collision and I debugged the program and the collidesWithItem() function keeps returning "False".

The items are added by clicking on the toolbar of the Form.

Down below is my code:

```
class graphicsScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene, QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(graphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.i = 0
        self.setSceneRect(-180, -90, 360, 180)
        global overlapped
        overlapped = 0

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        global host_cs
        global overlapped

        if host_cs == 1:
            if len(hostItem_list) == 0:
                self.host_item = host_Object()
                hostItem_list.append(self.host_item.host_pixItem)
            else:
                self.host_item = host_Object()
                for host in hostItem_list:
                    if self.host_item.host_pixItem.collidesWithItem(host):
                       print 'collision'
                       overlapped = 1
                       break

                    elif self.host_item.host_pixItem.collidesWithItem(host) == False:
                        overlapped = 0
                        if overlapped == 0: 
                            hostItem_list.append(self.host_item.host_pixItem)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        global host_cs
        if host_cs == 1:
            if overlapped == 0:
                self.addItem(self.host_item.host_pixItem)
                self.host_item.host_pixItem.setPos(event.scenePos())
                self.i += 1
                host_list.append('h' + str(self.i))

class host_Object(QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem, QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(host_Object, self).__init__(parent)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("host.png")
        self.host_pixItem = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap.scaled(30, 30, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.host_pixItem.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.host_pixItem.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable)

class Form(QtGui.QMainWindow, QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Form, self).__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('form.ui')

        self.ui.actionHost.triggered.connect(self.place_host)

        self.scene = graphicsScene()
        self.ui.view.setScene(self.scene)

    def place_host(self):
        host_cs = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    form = Form() 
    form.ui.show()  
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: `class host_Object(QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem, QtGui.QWidget)` what is it? This is forbidden! You cant inherit like this. This might be source of your problems. Same here: `class Form(QtGui.QMainWindow, QtGui.QWidget)`.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance is source of all evil things in application design.
Also it is forbidden in Qt to double inherit `QObject`.
So all your classes with multiple inheritance has big flaws.

Even `class host_Object(QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem, QtGui.QWidget)` is wrong and problematic since item can't be a `QWidget` and `QGraphicsItem` at the same time.

I would recommend you to avoid double inheritance as a general rule not only for Qt framework but for any language.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I deleted the second unnecessary inheritance but the program is still not detecting collision. What could the reason be for this?